# How to show these two objective functions are equivent?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, equivalence-relations

I have two objective function

$$
\min_f \quad \log (1 + \exp (f(x)^Tf(y) - f(x)^Tf(z)))
$$

And

$$
\min_f \quad \max(0,  f(x)^Tf(y) - f(x)^Tf(z))
$$

where $f$ is a function with its parameters, $x, y,z$ are some variables. How to show they are equivalent? For exmaple, optimize one will optimize the other.

The question is from  this [paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2016/file/6b180037abbebea991d8b1232f8a8ca9-Paper.pdf), the authors say that their Eq.(4) and Eq.(5) are equivalent. However, They don't provide some details in the paper.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions $h(t) = \log(1 + e^t)$ and $g(t) = \max\{0, t\}$ are both strictly increasing when $t \ge 0$. As long as $f(x)^T(f(y) - f(z)) \ge 0$ is guaranteed for all $f$, of course the same function will minimize both. (Note, by the way, that $x, y, z$ are not variables for this calculation - they are fixed.)

The authors only claim this is true under "mild assumptions" on $f$. Presumably these assumptions, along with whatever requirements are placed on $f$ by the definition of the role it plays in the paper, are sufficient to show that $f(x)^T(f(y) - f(z)) \ge 0$.